# exit not terminating the script

Tags: shell, command-substitution, exit, subshell

`exit` doesn't terminate the script when error is called..

## output

```
Error: Could not resolve localhost
after exit
```

## script

```
#!/bin/sh

resolve_ip (){
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        host="localhost"
        ip=$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)
    else
        host="$1"
        ip=$(dig +short $1)
    fi

    if [ -z "$ip" ]; then
        error "Could not resolve $host"
    fi

    echo "$ip"
}

error (){
    (>&2 echo "Error: $1")
    exit 1
}

master_host='google.com'

if [ "$(resolve_ip)" = "$(resolve_ip $master_host)" ]; then
    error "some error"
fi

echo "after exit"
exit
```

Comment: Aside: Why are you running the `echo` in `error` inside a subshell?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`exit` exits the current shell process¹.

In `$(resolve_ip)`, `resolve_ip` is running in a subshell process.

You can do:

```
my_ip=$(resolve_ip) || exit
master_ip=$(resolve_ip "$hostname") || exit
if [ "$my_ip" = "$master_ip" ]; ...
```

For the main shell to exit (with the same exit code as the subshell) when the subshell exits with a non-zero exit status.

Also, as `resolve_ip` is run in a subshell environment, the `$ip` and `$host` variables will not survive after that subshell returns.

Also note that the `(...)` in `(>&2 echo "Error: $1")` also starts a subshell. Not really necessary here unless you want to cover for the case where stderr is a broken pipe and writing the error message would cause a SIGPIPE delivery to the main shell process as `echo` is builtin.

Here, instead of returning the output over stdout, you could return it by storing it in user supplied variables:

```
resolve_ip (){ # args: ip_var [host]
    if [ "$#" -eq 1 ]; then
        host=localhost
        eval "$1="'$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)'
    else
        host=$2
        eval "$1="'$(dig +short "$2")'
    fi

    if eval '[ -z "${'"$1"'}" ]'; then
        error "Could not resolve $host"
    fi
}

# ...

resolve_ip my_ip
resolve_ip master_ip "$hostname"

if [ "$my_ip" = "$master_ip" ]; ...
```

---

<sup>¹ Strictly speaking subshell environments don't have to be implemented with child processes, and some shells like `ksh93` don't as an optimisation, but still `exit` there only exits the subshell, not the main shell. `ksh93` however has a `${ ...; }` form or command substitution that doesn't involve a subshell environment, so `exit` in that would exit the main shell.</sup>